# get the matching rows for multiple columns pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Consider my first data frame `df1`

```
      col1 col2  col3
0    hello    q     1
1    world    q     2
2  welcome    r     3
3    hello    t     4
```

---

And second data frame `df2`

```
    col1 col2  col3
0  hello    q     2
```

---

Need output like

```
      col1 col2  col3
0    hello    q     2
1    world    q     2
2  welcome    r     3
3    hello    t     4
```

`'col1'` and `'col2'` should be equal and if `'col3'` differs get the output and replace the value in dataframe first

I tried to use `merge`

```
df1.merge(df2, on=['col1', 'col2'])

    col1 col2  col3_x  col3_y
0  hello    q       1       2
```

But I don't know what to do next.

Comment: first.loc[first['col1'].isin(second['col1']), 'col1'] can able to get the matched rows for one column

Answer (score 1):

### Option 1

`merge`, `append`, `drop_duplicates`

```
df1.drop('col3', 1).merge(df2).append(df1).drop_duplicates(['col1', 'col2'])

      col1 col2  col3
0    hello    q     2
1    world    q     2
2  welcome    r     3
3    hello    t     4
```

---

### Option 2

`set_index` and `combine_first`

```
cols = ['col1', 'col2']
df2.set_index(cols).combine_first(
    df1.set_index(cols)
).reset_index().astype(df1.dtypes)

      col1 col2  col3
0    hello    q     2
1    hello    t     4
2  welcome    r     3
3    world    q     2
```

Comment: That will only work because the row to replace with happens to have the same index value.  That seems coincidental for the chosen toy data.

Comment: Agree OP did state they wanted to match on col1 and col2 not index.  Thanks.